# Optional Int to Arrays in Swift - Average Function

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I write an average function in swift in where input in an array of optional Ints? Here's what I wrote so far:

```
func ave(array: [Int?] -> Double?) {

    var mysum = 0
    for num in array {
        mysum += num
    }
    return Double(mysum)/Double(array.count)
}
```

I read a lot of Optional ints but I don't know how to implement that when the input in an array of optional ints... Any help?

Comment: What should happen when you get a nil value?

Comment: if i encounter nil, i want to print a message.

Comment: You're gonna need to change your method to `ave(array: [Int?]) -> Double?` too.

Comment: After you've printed your message, do you want to return nil, do you want to pretend the number was 0 or some other value, or do you want to continue calculating the average like it wasn't there (exclude it from the array count)?

Answer (score 5):

Here it is in Swift 2, since it is only a few days away now:

```
func ave(array: [Int?]) -> Double? {
    guard array.filter({ $0 == nil }).isEmpty else {
        print("One of the Ints was nil")
        return nil
    }
    return Double(array.reduce(0, { $0 + $1! })) / Double(array.count)
}
```

The opening `guard` statement checks `array` for any `nil` members, and returns `nil` after printing a message if it finds any.

If no `nil` is found, we use a simple `reduce` statement to calculate the sum of the array members, then divide by the count.

Here are some examples of the results:

```
ave([1,2,3])      // 2
ave([1,2,nil])    // nil (and the message will print)
ave([])           // Double.NaN (because you're dividing by zero)
```

---

If you want it in Swift 1.2, the implementation is not all that different:

```
func ave(array: [Int?]) -> Double? {
    if array.filter({ $0 == nil }).isEmpty {
        return Double(array.reduce(0, combine: { $0 + $1! })) / Double(array.count)
    } else {
        print("One of the Ints was nil")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Very beautiful implementation.

Comment: Really awesome implementation. I should really take a moment and check Swift 2.

Comment: You should consider if `array.count` is `0`

Comment: @rintaro In Swift, dividing by `0` returns `Double.NaN` instead of crashing the application. I would consider `NaN` to be the best option. You don't crash, you don't get a mysterious `nil` that could mean any other problem, and you can test for `NaN` to specifically deal with an empty array.

Comment: `(Double(12) / Double(0)).isNaN` is `false`, whereas `(Double(0) / Double(0)).isNaN` is `true` :)

Comment: @rintaro Correct, but you'll have a hard time getting that result out of this function.

Comment: Yeah, I know, just for a curious. Thx for the answer.

Comment: fix `combine: { $0 + $1! })` to `combine: +)` , please

Comment: @maxpovver Did you try that yourself? The compiler considers it ambiguous. `$1` needs to be forcefully unwrapped using `!`, so it is not a simple addition. At any rate, I personally believe in being explicit; my code will be easier to read 6 months later, even if your syntactic trick did work.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make an `if let` check in your `for` loop.

```
func ave(array: [Int?])-> Double {
    var arraySize = array.count
    var mysum = 0
    for num in array {
        if let num = num{
            mysum += num
        }else{
            arraySize--
            println("Is nil")
        }
    }
    return Double(mysum)/Double(arraySize)
}
```

As you maybe see, I've added a variable called `arraySize` because you need to check what's the size of your real array. Without the nils. Otherwise your final calculation doesn't work as wanted. Also I've changed your func-header a little bit. There was a mistake in your code before:

```
func ave(array: [Int?] -> Double?) {
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The return-value has to be outside of the `()`:

```
func ave(array: [Int?])-> Double {
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can do average func in two lines (you can do this in one line, of course, but then you get duplicate code - `array.filter { $0 != nil }`):

```
func average(array: [Int?]) -> Double {
    let arrayWhithoutNils = array.filter { $0 != nil }
    return arrayWhithoutNils.count > 0 ? (arrayWhithoutNils.map { Double($0!) }.reduce(0, combine: +) / Double(arrayWhithoutNils.count)) : 0
}

print(average([1, 2, 3])) // 2
print(average([nil, 4, 5, nil])) // 4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array with optional elements, it usually helps to use `flatmap` to first give you an array with no optionals...

```
func ave ( nums:[Int?] ) -> Double?
{
    var answer : Double? = .None
    let realInts = nums.flatMap { $0 }

    if ( realInts.count > 0 ) {
        var accum : Int = 0
        realInts.map { accum += $0 }
        answer = Double(accum) / Double(realInts.count)
    }

    return answer
}
```

Comment: The second example doesn't compile. Where does `S` come from?

Comment: Nevermind, it seemed to work but when I went back I found the playground had not actually executed it - thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
func average(numbers: [Int?]) -> Double {
    let sum = numbers.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 ?? 0) }
    let numValidElms = numbers.filter { $0 != nil }.count

    let delta = numbers.count - numValidElms
    if delta > 0 {
        println("Found \(delta) nil values")
    }

    if numValidElms > 0 {
        return Double(sum) / Double(numValidElms)
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Examples

```
average([nil]) // 0
average([1,2,3]) // 2
average([1, nil, 2]) // 1.5
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
func ave(array: [Int?])-> Double {

    var mysum = 0
    var c = 0
    for num in array {
        if let n = num {
           mysum += n
           c++
    }
    return Double(mysum)/Double(c)
}
```